# Python - Find line number from text file

Tags: python, numbers, line

**I'm writing code that looks in a text file, and sees if the input is in there.**

E.g.,

**I input "pizza"**

**My textfile contains:**

```
bread
pizza
pasta
tomato
```

Is there a way to print the line number the word pizza is on?

Comment: Start reading thru the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and practicing the examples, pretty soon you will start getting ideas - try some of them out in the shell to find out what works and what doesn't, look through the docs for the [*built-in* functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) to see if any can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

index = [x for x in range(len(content)) if 'pizza' in content[x].lower()]
```

Part (1) of the code reads each line as a separate list in variable "content".

Part (2) populates out the line # of content only if 'pizza' exists in that line. [x for x in range(len(content))] simply populates all index values, while 'if 'pizza' in content[x].lower()' keeps the line # that matches the string.

Comment: Can you provide some explanation, please?

Comment: Sorry, I have added the explanation

Comment: What do I print then to give me the line number? What variable is the line number?

Comment: index contains the list of line numbers. print(index)

Comment: thanks :) really helped

Comment: I can't use the number, as it is in squared brackets? e.g. i can't do 1 + 'index'. Anyway around this?

Comment: 1+index[0] - it's a list, so you will have to index it

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways of accomplishing this:

1. Storing the entire file in memory so you only read it once
2. Reading through the file on every search, but not having to store it

For method 1, first read in every line and then get the index that the word is on:

```
with open('path.txt') as f: data = f.readlines()
line_no = data.index("pizza")
```

Alternatively, go through the file to find the index:

```
with open('path.txt') as f:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
        if line == "pizza":
            break
    else: # for loop ended => line not found
        line_no = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import re
import os # You can go without is if you have other means to get your filepath

i = 1
matches = []
target = raw_input("Please type string to match\n")
with open(os.getenv("SOME_PATH") + "/myfile.txt") as fic: # open("myfile.txt") if in your current directory
     for line in fic:
         if re.search(target, line):
             print "Found at line {}".format(i)
             matches.append(i)
         i = i +1
if not len(matches):
    raise Exception, "target not found"
```

By doing this, you can input a regular expression and it should work (i.e. if you input "p.zza" or "^p.*", it will work.). The list `matches` will contain all indices of lines that match the input pattern.

Answer (score -1):

```
print next (i for i,v in enumerate (open (fname),1) if v == needle)
```

Comment: You don't want to close the file afterward?