# Previous element count in text file

Tags: python-3.x, line

I have 2 text file that includes unique words and separated each line one word. I want to find how many line before specific word in file. Assume that

```
bread
pizza
pasta
tomato
```

is textfile1.

```
pizza
tomato
```

is textfile2.

I want to get

```
pizza 1 
tomato 3
```

as output. I tried the code [Python - Find line number from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429941/python-find-line-number-from-text-file?rq=1) but because of my text files are huge it does not work correctly(textfile1 consists of 45999 line textfile2 consists of 2698 lines). How can solve this problem? Thank you..

Comment: Are both files sorted?

Comment: What kind of problems are you facing? 45999 lines (with single words) is not huge, it could be around 500KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the words in `textfile2` into a set, and then iterate through the lines of `textfile1` with indices generated from `enumerate`. Output the word with the current index if it is in the aforementioned set:

```
with open('textfile2') as file:
    words = {line.rstrip() for line in file}
with open('textfile1') as file:
    for index, line in enumerate(file):
        word = line.rstrip()
        if word in words:
            print(word, index)
```